# Change Page for jQuery Mobile between two html files

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make a simple site with two pages, "Search" and "Results".

At first, I had a multi-page template working fairly well.  I would change the page, and on page change I would use ajax to get the results.  The problem was that I wanted to be able to load the results page without first going back to the search page.

I want to pass parameters to the results page via the querystring so that I can have something like this:

`search.html` + "some search terms"  ->  `results.html?q=some+search+terms`

The problem is that I can't seem to get anything to work right when I split up the html into two files.

I try calling

```
$.mobile.changePage("results.html?q=" + escape(search))
```

on the search page, but the `$(document).ready` function is not firing.  I kind of get why it doesn't, since `changePage` is loading the second page into the DOM?

I also tried manually redirecting, in which case the `$(document).ready` function does fire on results.html, but using the back button or going back to the search page doesn't fire THAT `$(document).ready`.

I tried wiring up the `pagechange` function to search.html, assuming that this would fire when I load the second page, but nothing happened.

Does anyone have suggestions as to how I would pull this off?  Or the best way to get the results page to act more independent of the search page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input guys. I used a plugin that allows me to use faux-query parameters in the hash for a multi-page layout.

https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params

I just added this in and ran the search on page change, getting those page parameters for the search.

Answer (score 0):

I've been bitten by this too, it really isn't a good idea to pass parameters through the query string and it makes jQueryMobile behave in an odd way.

Instead I've been using sessionStorage which works perfectly. You could also use a cookie.

Comment: dang, I'm trying to find a good way to do this, because of how the browser behaves on my phone.  If I close and reopen the browser, it reloads that url, making session storage iffy.  Plus I'm looking to be able to post a specific results page to Facebook or something.

Comment: Since a jQuery Mobile website does not reload the DOM, you can just save data in a JavaScript variable and access it on every page. This will perform **much** faster than using `sessionStorage` (pretty much any persistent browser storage creates a lot of CPU overhead each read/write, that in mind if you do use it, make sure to serialize a single object of data to perform a single read/write when necessary rather than a bunch of smaller ones, the overhead comes from initializing the data connection).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure where you're actually having issues, but here is some important jQuery Mobile specific info that can help you.

First, read the big yellow section at the top of this page: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

`document.ready` does not fire when a page is brought into the DOM from an external document. Instead you need to use event delegation and the page-events specified in the link above. Most likely you want to use `pageinit` as a replacement for `document.ready`.

Then read the top section of this page: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html (the part about `$.mobile.changePage()`).

The important part about the second link is that you can pass data via the `$.mobile.changePage()` function like so:

```
$.mobile.changePage('results.html', { data : { q : search } });
```

You can even set the `type` option to `post` so there will not be a query-string sent (this should ensure you don't get multiple of the same page in the DOM at a time).

```
$.mobile.changePage('results.html', { data : { q : search }, type : 'post' });
```

Another fix would be to manually add the `data-url` attribute to the `<div data-role="page" id="results">` page. When you grab a page like this:

```
 $.mobile.changePage("results.html?q=search+term+here");
```

It's `data-url` gets set to: `results.html?q=search+term+here`. If you manually set the `data-url` to `results.html` then you can navigate to the page like this:

```
 $.mobile.changePage("results.html", { data : { q : 'search+term+here' } });
```

Which will look first for the `data-role="page"` element that has the `data-url` attribute set to `results.html` before re-loading the pseudo-page via AJAX.